# Define Zookeeper znode for wurstmeister/kafka docker image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I would like to set the kafka znodes at another znode and not on root.
e.g 
the default znodes for kafka are:

```
/admin
/brokers
/cluster
/config
```

but I would like to reorganize them and move them into kafka znode

```
/kafka/admin
/kafka/brokers
/kafka/cluster
/kafka/config
```

there is any property for docker-compose to have default zookeeper znode?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking at some logic in the ZooKeeper client and notice that this is actually possible. It was just not documented!

You can specify a chroot in the `zookeeper.connect` setting. For example:

```
zookeeper.connect=ZK_HOST:2181/somepath
```

and Kafka will only write under /somepath in ZooKeeper

I opened a PR to mention it in the docs: https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/5358

---

Original Answer:

I don't think it's possible. The Zookeeper paths are hardcoded in Kafka and I'm not aware of a method to prepend to them using configuration.

That said, that sounds like a sensible requirement so you could try to make Kafka support this. As it would introduce a new configuration, you would need to create a KIP: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Improvement+Proposals

Comment: Thank you. I hoped to have an answer to how to due it, but must admit that for the moment its not possible.

Comment: I have updated my answer as it turns out this is possible!